# Splitting integers and strings into other lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this

```
list = ['John', 21, 'Smith', 30, 'James', 25]
```

and I want to split them into the following

```
name = ['John', 'Smith', 'James']
age = [21, 30, 25]
```

Comment: [split list into 2 lists corresponding to every other element](//stackoverflow.com/q/23130300)

Comment: Hello Emmanuel, welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very basic, you should be able to find lots of answers by using your preferred search engine. It's also not entirely clear whether your input array has always the same pattern (alternating strings and ints) or if you have to parse the elements and check types. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. Don't use `keywords` and `built-in` names as variable names.

***Using Slicing***

[Understanding Slicing Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

```
lst=['John', 21, 'Smith', 30, 'James', 25]
name=lst[::2] 
age=lst[1::2]
```

---

Or you can use ***List Comprehension***

[List Comprehension Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520)

```
name=[val for idx,val in enumerate(lst) if idx%2==0]
age=[val for idx,val in enumerate(lst) if idx%2==1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list. Append an element to the list name if the index of the element can be divided by two without remainder. If there is a remainder when dividing the index by two append the element to the list age. List indexes start at 0. enumerate makes the index of an element available while iterating a list. Checking remainder of division is done with the modulo operator.

```
lst = ['John', 21, 'Smith', 30, 'James', 25]

#Create list name to store the names
name = []
#Create list age to store the age
age = []

# use for loop to access every element of lst
# using enumerate(lst) let's us access the index of every element in the variable index see reference [0]
# The indexes of the list elements are as following:
# John: 0, 21: 1, Smith: 2, 30: 3, James: 4, 25: 5
for index,element in enumerate(lst):
    #Check if the index of an element can be divided by 2 without a remainder
    #This is true for the elements John, Smith and James:
    #0 / 2 = 0 remainder 0
    #2 / 2 = 1 remainder 0
    #4 / 2 = 2 remainder 0
    if index % 2 == 0:
       name.append(element)
    # If the division of the index of an element yields remainder, add the element to the list age
    # This is true for the elements 21, 30 and 25:
    # 1 / 2 = 0 remainder 1
    # 3 / 2 = 1 remainder 1
    # 5 / 2 = 2 remainder 1
    else:
        age.append(element)

print(name)
print(age)
```

References:

[0] https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate
[1] https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations.

Answer (score 0):

A less convenient way is to use list indexing:

```
list = ['John', 21, 'Smith', 30, 'James', 25]
name=[list[0],list[2],list[4]]
print(name)
age=[list[1],list[3],list[5]]
print(age)
```